# Install PHP extensions to wordpress container using docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I need to install some php extensions to my wordpress installation to run MailPoet (https://kb.mailpoet.com/article/152-minimum-requirements-for-mailpoet-3#php_extension).

I have a docker compose installation. My docker-compose.yml:

```
---
version: '3.3'
services:
   gnxcontainer:
      container_name: gnxcontainer
      image: jsonderulo/user:latest
      networks:
         - reverse-proxy-network
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
         - /home/user/.env:/usr/src/app/.env
         - /home/user/docker/gnxcontainer/filestorage:/usr/src/app/filestorage

   caddy:
      container_name: caddy
      image: caddy:2.4.5
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
  - /home/user/docker/caddy/data:/data
  - /home/user/docker/caddy/config:/config
  - /home/user/docker/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
  - /home/user/docker/caddy/logs/:/var/log/

 wordpress:
depends_on:
  - db
image: wordpress:latest
volumes:
  - wordpress_files:/var/www/html
  - /home/user/docker/upload.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
ports:
  - "81:80"
networks:
  - reverse-proxy-network
restart: unless-stopped
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD

db:
image: mysql:5.7
volumes:
  - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  - reverse-proxy-network
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
  MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
  MYSQL_USER: wordpress
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD

volumes:
wordpress_files:
db_data:
upload.ini:

networks:
reverse-proxy-network:
ipam:
  config:
    - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how I need to change my configuration if I want to install php extensions inside my wordpress container?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How are you trying to install extensions, and what happens when you try to install an extension? 
It's not clear to me from this description what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [mailpoet/wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailpoet/wordpress) image from the docker hub? The docs are a bit nonexistent on how to use the image but I can get it running fine locally with this setup below...

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  # here is our mysql container
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      # our persistent local mapping
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our wordpress mailpoet container
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: mailpoet/wordpress:wp-6.2_php8.1_20230425.1
    volumes:
      # our persistent local mapping
      - ./themes/example:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/example:delegated
      - ./mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./error-logging.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini
      - ./logs:/var/www/html/wp-content/logs
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:

      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1

      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEiY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');
        
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'no-reply@mailpoet.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Docker Wordpress Mailpoet');

        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }

    networks:
    - wordpress

  # here is our mailhog server
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - wordpress

networks:
  wordpress:
```

In your `functions.php` you will need to add this for Mailhog to work...

**funtions.php** (partial)

```php
// add the action
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);

// configure PHPMailer to send through SMTP
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($phpmailer) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // host details
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->Host = WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->Port = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT;
    // from details
    $phpmailer->From = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME;
    // login details
    $phpmailer->Username = WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $phpmailer->Password = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD;

});
```

Before deploying via `docker-compose up -d`, you will need to create two `.ini` files alongside your `docker-compose.yml` file.

[image]

**uploads.ini**

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_execution_time = 600
```

**error-logging.ini**

```ini
#error_reporting = E_ALL
error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR ^ E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/www/html/wp-content/logs/debug.log
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = On
ignore_repeated_source = Off
html_errors = Off
```

Now you are ready to `docker-compose up -d` in your project. Once you've run this, your project will look like this...

[image]

Now go to admin and install the Mailpoet plugin...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailpoet/

Once installed, head over to the Mailpoet settings and go to the `Send with...` tab, and click `Configure` SMTP settings.

[image]

Add the same SMTP settings as used in the `docker-compose.yml`

> It looks like these SMTP mailpoet settings can also be defined by filters...
> https://kb.mailpoet.com/article/274-list-of-filters-and-actions

Once you've activated these settings, go back to the config screen and click `Send a test email`.

> This email can be any address because we are capturing all emails sent
> through SMTP to our Mailhog inbox.

Once you've sent the test, head over to Mailhog to see the test at this port address...

http://localhost:8025/

[image]
[image]

Now you can start testing Mailpoet locally in docker.